# Can you use reCaptcha on localhost?

Tags: localhost, recaptcha

I am creating a WP website, and want to use reCaptcha on the contact form.  However, I am still developing it on localhost via Xampp.

Can I get the reCaptcha setup now?  Do I just put in the website's domain name (ie: domain.com) in the setup field, and will it still work will in localhost?

I saw some old documentation that says you can enter localhost or 127.0.0.1 to the list of domains?  Is this still valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Better idea: detect localhost clients and skip the reCaptcha check for those visitors.

Comment: I went ahead and created the reCaptcha on my development site.  It gets installed fine, it just says it doesn't work on local host, and I can live with that.  I just wanted to make sure it was installed and will be functional when I go live.  (I don't want to add localhost to the reCaptcha list of domains, because I am using this key on another production site).